# Generating key characters and appending them to a string

Tags: python, encryption

I am currently working on a project with 'Encryption' at school, the first task is to do the following:

1. import random
2. Create an empty string variable named 'key'
3. repeat 8 times
4. Choose a random number between 33 and 162 (The ascii table)
5. Take the chosen random number, and add it to the 'key' variable
6. print the key variable
7. Tell the user to remember this key to decrypt the message

I would also like to say, I know there is not a message to encrypt currently, I am aware of this. This is just practice that needs to be done. Here is my code:

```
import random

key = ''

for i in range(0,8):
    random_number = (random.randint(33,162))
    str(chr(random_number.append(key)))

print(key)
print("Remember this key to decrypt your message!")
```

when inside of the shell (after running, I get the following error...)

```
"str(chr(random_number.append(key)))

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'"
```

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` method is for list and list-like objects, not for simple, immutable types like `int,str,tuple` etc. i think you wanted this:

```
key +=str(random_number)
```

instead to set `key = key + str(random_number)`

Comment: Got it! This helped a ton! Quick question, I'm not too sure how to convert the numbers to ascii, I know you use the 'chr' function but I am not fully educated on the chr and ord functions currently!

Comment: @Matt Your use of `chr` seems correct in this case.

Comment: yes, as long as the int is in the right range, `chr(x)` should work. if you want to convert your random number into its `chr(x)` representation, just call `chr()` instead of `str()` since `str` just converts the int into a string ie `str(1) = '1'`

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the help guys absolutely amazing :D

Answer (score 0):

You can only append to lists. You have an empty string to which you have to add. Now think which option we use with strings and you got it ;-)

Comment: I'm not really sure, I am going to presume you mean a list, or is it the ''.join(key) feature? because that doesn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
import random

key = ''

for i in range(0,8):
    random_number = (random.randint(33,162))
    key += str(random_number) # main change

print(key)
print("Remember this key to decrypt your message!")
```